# Changing data type of field in .net

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, strongly-typed-dataset

Is it possible to change the data type of a field/property in .net through reflection or something?

I am looking for this feature, as there is problem in Strongly Typed Datasets. Strongly Typed Datasets don't give You the flexibility of changing data types of nullable types. See a related link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879095/nullable-int-column-in-dataset). So, if there is a possibility to change the data type at run time, this problem can be eliminated. Also, to add; as per this [MSDN Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/407cca6d-2364-47ca-821e-77a1cad574cf/typed-dataset-nullable-support?forum=adodotnetdataset); Microsoft team is not very keen to provide this support.

Comment: If you don't know the type of the column, you probably shouldn't be using a strongly typed data set.

Comment: I don't know if you can use `dynamic` or not, but there is a good reason why people use that only when they have to.

Comment: @MikeChristensen I know the data type but unfortunately when I try to iterate the data table, I get errors as the Dataset Designer of VS has the only property of Throw Exception.

Comment: @MikeChristensen This problem only comes when the datatype are supposed to get null values from database and they are unable to cast them to int, double, float etc.

Comment: @shankbond - You need to be checking `IsXXXNull()` beforehand.

Comment: Where do you get cannot change types of nullalbe?  From the documentation.  "An exception is generated when changing this property after the column has begun storing data."

Comment: @MikeChristensen Thanks, but I saw this workaround at a number of places in the internet, I am using LINQ mostly to query/transform this Dataset, so using this syntax every where, which is I am avoiding somewhat.I am looking for a more elegant solution :)

Comment: @shankbond - The elegant solution is not to use outdated frameworks like *typed data sets*.  They are subject to the limitations of the CLR back at the time.  These days, there are *far* superior ORMs such as the Entity Framework or NHibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this is not a bug; it's due to the difference between dbnull ie unknown value and null ie a reference pointing nowhere. It's compounded by the fact that Microsoft themselves seem to be poor at explaining it, judging by some of the opaque and unhelpful responses on Connect and elsewhere.

There are a number of solutions to this issue, depending on what you are trying to achieve. If you are using databinding, then the binding mechanism mostly handles this transparently for you; if you are hitting the dataset directly in code the designer will have built Isxxxnull / setxxxnull methods for you to check the value before you use it. Finally you can change the datatype to system.object, or you can overtype the NullValue in the designer to enter another value if you wish, as long as that value is valid for the datatype - eg 0 or -1 for an int.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of.  Type information and binding is determined at compile-type, so there's not a way to change it at run time.

One pattern to use to change typing is the [adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).  This could just pass through all other fields and then "convert" the field in question to a new type.  Of course, this happens at compile-time as well.

If you expand a little more on what you're trying to do there may be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

`Dataset`s are rather dated and stem from .net v1.0. Microsoft is never going make changes or additions to them. In general a better approach would be strongly typed POCOs. You can even create multiple, strongly typed properties that all use the same backing storage (of type object). You would need to test for the correct type before accessing the corresponding property.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it takes a lot of time creating these POCO based models and then filling them with ADO.net. It is beacause of this reason I went to Dataset, but now I am stuck :(

Comment: Both Linq to SQL and the EF will create POCO or POCO like bits for you.